# Mysql: Writing to logfile after insert in table

Tags: mysql

Problem is this: I have to write the data to a physical file each time after a certain table is updated.

Normally I would do this with a trigger, for example:

```
CREATE TRIGGER log_to_file AFTER INSERT ON LOG
BEGIN
...
END
```

How do I refer to the data that triggers a database trigger in the first place from within the trigger code ? This is namely the data I have to analyze and have to write to a file.

Comment: check out `NEW` and `OLD` keywords

Comment: @willem-noorduin, I need to do the same thing, did you ever come up with a workable solution?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you want. As per my understanding , you want to refer a row that is just inserted. You can refer that with NEW in code. So this might work for you.

```
    CREATE TABLE LOG
    (
    ID INT(11) NOT NULL,
    Description NVARCHAR(50) NULL,
    )

    CREATE TRIGGER log_to_file AFTER INSERT ON LOG
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN

/* Logic can be put here for each inserted row */

    INSERT INTO any_table (ID,Description,Date) VALUES(New.ID,New.Description,SYSDATE())

    END
```